# Is the cost function always of the form $w \cdot x$?

Tags: microeconomics, cost-functions

Consider a profit-maximizing (or cost-minimizing) firm with a production function $f(x,y)$. If I am given the inputs $x,y$, the input costs $w,r$ and the cost function $c(w,r,q) = w^{0.4}r^{0.6}q$, does that mean it is related to $wx+ry$, possibly in the following way:

$w^*x_q + r^*y_q = w^{0.4}r^{0.6}q$ where $(w^*, r^*) := \underset{w,r}{\text{argmin}}(wx + ry) \text{ subject to } q=f(x,y)$ and $(x_q,y_q)$ are the inputs that produce output $q$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Giskard I am given the cost function $c(w,r,q) = w^{0.4}r^{0.6}q$. I read that cost functions are of the form $C = w \cdot x$ (where $w$ is the input price vector and $x$ is the demand vector).  I am confused if they are the same thing or not. As in, if $c$ is the optimal $C$ (cost) of producing an output of $q$?

Comment: Yes, $c(w,r,q)$ is the minimal cost of producing $q$ units given the input prices $w,r$.

Comment: If the firm could choose the prices $w,r$ without constraint, it would set their level to $0$ (or even $-\infty$).